# Having trouble setting up up an Apache name-based virtual host on my local system

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I am unable to configure the virtual host. When I finish configuring to inspect going to the page I showed in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/gdex.dev.conf`, you go to the root folder of the `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`)

Here is my config in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/gdex.dev.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName gdex.dev
        ServerAlias www.gdex.dev
    ServerRoot /var/www/html/gdex.dev/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/gdex.dev/

    <Directory "/var/www/html/gdex.dev">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gdex.dev.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gdex.dev.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the content in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost  
127.0.1.1 xubuntu

127.0.0.1 gdex.dev
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Image Output](http://i.imgur.com/crGP7Vq.png])

Answer (score 0):

In your question you are showing the configuration being set in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/gdex.dev.conf` but is there a symbolic link set from that to `sites-enabled`?

That configuration being in `sites-available` simply means that config available for use; `sites-enabled` means the config is now actually enabled and will be loaded by Apache.

You can set the config to be in `sites-available` using a command like this:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/gdex.dev.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gdex.dev.conf
```

And then reload Apache config via this standard `service reload` command:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

After doing that `service reload`, check your virtual host list running this command:

```
sudo apachectl -S
```

The output should then be something like this:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         port 80 namevhost gdex.dev (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gdex.dev.conf:1)
```

The thing to note is the line that has `port 80 namevhost gdex.dev` in it. If somehow that doesn’t show up, try to force restarting the Apache server like this:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And then check the output of `sudo apachectl -S` again for that `port 80 namevhost gdex.dev` item.